# Modifying SELinux settings to allow for MySQL to run on CentOS7

Tags: centos, mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.6 on Cent OS 7 with SELinux enabled and am trying to get past the error (in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`):

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1424111345.853:558): avc:  denied  { execmem } for  pid=1795 comm="mysqld" scontext=system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tclass=process
```

My install process is fairly simple, in a virutalbox vm I use a CentOS7 iso to install the OS with minimal selected as the installation type.

I then add the mysql yum repository by running: `yum install http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm`

Then installing MySQL using: `yum install mysql-community-server`

Don't see any errors with the install but when trying to run systemctl start mysqld I ultimately get to the SElinux message above.

I took a quick online class on SELinux and came across the audit2allow troubleshooting tool and it tells me that I'm missing a type a type enforcement allow rule. Running audit2allow -a gives me:

```
#============= mysqld_t ==============
allow mysqld_t self:process execmem;
```

What's keeping me from moving on to actually creating the module as it's suggesting is simply that I finding it hard to believe that SELinux doesn't have the policy down by now for MySQL to run without having to modify it's config.  Have other's had to do this or what have you done to get MySQL running on CentOS 7?

Comment: may be that is the reason: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75912

Comment: Yup that's it. All that googling/searching and that never came up for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL bug in build of 5.6.23 caused the issue: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75912, using 5.6.24 or later resolves the problem with SELinux.